# what is the java script code to open popup on clicking the grid cell value

Tags: javascript, gridview, popup

I want to show some values on a page using gridview but the problem is that I want to open a popup when I click the value of cell by making that value a hyperlink to open a popup.
by this code instead of opening a popup page is redirected to that popup page only not like a popup. I have used java script but I guess its not perfectly correct according to my code to show the data on page .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ClientName"  DataTextField="ClientName"  DataNavigateUrlFields="ClientName"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="TotalVehicles"  DataTextField="TotalVehicles"  DataNavigateUrlFields="TotalVehicles"   DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween4Hours"  DataTextField="LiveVehiclesBetween4Hours" DataNavigateUrlFields="LiveVehiclesBetween4Hours" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween4To10Hours"  DataTextField="LiveVehiclesBetween4To10Hours"  DataNavigateUrlFields="LiveVehiclesBetween4To10Hours" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween10To24Hours"  DataTextField="LiveVehiclesBetween10To24Hours" DataNavigateUrlFields="LiveVehiclesBetween10To24Hours" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="LiveVehiclesFromMoreThan24Hours"  DataTextField="LiveVehiclesFromMoreThan24Hours" DataNavigateUrlFields="LiveVehiclesFromMoreThan24Hours" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
        <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="ClientName" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalVehicles" HeaderText="TotalVehicles" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LiveVehiclesBetween4Hours" HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween4Hours" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LiveVehiclesBetween4To10Hours" HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween4To10Hours" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LiveVehiclesBetween10To24Hours" HeaderText="LiveVehiclesBetween10To24Hours" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LiveVehiclesFromMoreThan24Hours" HeaderText="LiveVehiclesFromMoreThan24Hours" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkView" Text="View" NavigateUrl="javascript:;" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" var=popup Target="_blank">POLICY</asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id=ClientName]").click(function () {
            var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
            window.open("LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?rowIndex=" + rowIndex, "Popup", "width=350,height=100");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i am not able to paste the whole code please help me

Comment: <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ClientName"  DataTextField="ClientName"  DataNavigateUrlFields="ClientName"  />
                                                         <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="TotalVehicles"  DataTextField="TotalVehicles"  DataNavigateUrlFields="TotalVehicles"   DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />

Comment: these are the two cell clientname and total vehicle i want that if i click on these value like TCS which is client name then client detail should come on popup , not open in another page.

Comment: please help me with the java script which best work for this code .

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action browser would take which is to open the url referenced in the href.

Use `event.preventDefault()` to do it:

```
 $("[id=ClientName]").click(function (event) {// include event argument

        event.preventDefault();// prevent browser folloing url

        var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
        window.open("LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?rowIndex=" + rowIndex, "Popup", "width=350,height=100");
    });
```

Comment: hi charlietfl thanks for your reply but this script still not working as i am not able to open a popup and still livevehicledetail.aspx  page is opening .

Comment: asp:templatefeild and asp:hyperlink are useless code they are not being used .

Comment: i am able to give hyperlinking on cell by
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="ClientName"  DataTextField="ClientName"  DataNavigateUrlFields="ClientName"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/LiveVehicleDetail.aspx?id={0}" />
but i want script to open the popup whith this asp.property